# Android Java: Activity called AFTER onPause( )

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

My app allows the user to choose a file, through a chooser intent, and then opens the file with an asyncTask.
Now, I log all procedures entries and this is what I see (Eclipse logcat):

```
02-01 11:08:21.229: D/LogViewer(337): + onPause()
02-01 11:08:21.497: D/LogViewer(337): + onItemSelected()
02-01 11:08:21.507: D/LogViewer(337): + onItemSelected()
02-01 11:08:26.667: D/LogViewer(337): + onActivityResult(requestCode:0, resultCode:-1, data:Intent { dat=file:MyLog.gzip })
02-01 11:08:26.731: D/LogCollectTask(337): + onPreExecute()
02-01 11:08:26.737: D/LogCollectTask(337): + doInBackground()
02-01 11:08:27.157: D/LogViewer(337): + onResume()
```

**How come there are calls to LogViewer AFTER it is paused? Shouldn't it be inactive until onResume() ?**

PS: I know that it is what it is, but I am strugling to understand Android behavior.

Comment: is the onItemSelected called after your asynctask's onPostExecute ?

Comment: @fedepaol, What I posted it the actual logcat message list (the relevant part) with all the procedures that are called, in that order. You can see when the onPreExecute() of the AsyncTask is called, and of course onPostExecute() is called much later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I am gonna take that since the chooser intent requires user interaction it superseeds the Paused state, unless someone knows better and corrects me.